# Android market app not showing in mobile

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

we have an android app uploaded to the Android Market and we can browse it through the desktop computer, but unfortunately, the app can't be seen from a mobile terminal (we tried with a Motorola A953 with Android 2.2) and a with a Nexus S with Android 2.3.6) and the application simply doesn't appear in the search results where it should be.

The application is called Voetbal.nl

Any idea what the problem could be?

Best,
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

Does your app by any chance require a specific API level, heigher than the one the Nexus has (10)? You can check them out here: https://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

You can also check if it's available for download in the country you are located in. I know it's an obvious thing but omitting something like this by accident happens more often than we'd like to admit. :)

Comment: well the download should be available, as I'm located in the same country

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout your manifest file. its filtered out your device.

please refer http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

Fixed; it was just a matter of time, since Google updated the app after like 30 minutes.